# Mousemove function not being called

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I've got an es6 class, that binds a `handleElement` on mousedown, and on drag it will resize the `variableElement`.

The problem is it won't output the `console.log('move')`. Although if I rename the `_mousemove` function, I get an undefined method error on the two eventListeners...

I can't seem to figure out what's happening?

```js
export default class DragResizer {
  constructor(handleElement, variableElement) {
    this.handleElement = window.document.getElementsByClassName(handleElement)[0];
    this.variableElement = window.document.getElementsByClassName(variableElement)[0];

    console.log('bind');
    this.handleElement.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', this._mousemove);
      console.log('down');
    });

    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
      console.log('up');
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', this._mousemove);
    });
  }

  _mousemove(event) {
    console.log('move');
    this.variableElement.style.flexBasis = `${event.clientX}px`;
  }
}
```

Comment: try using an arrow function for the mousedown listener to preserve the context(i.e. `this` )

Comment: @Musa no luck. The context doesn't seem to be the problem here. It seems like the mousemove isn't being called..

Comment: Don't you need to reference `console` within the class, as `_mousemove` is private?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_mousemove` won't get called since the `this.` in `this._mousemove` does not refer to `DragResizer` (it refers to `window`)

The old way (without using an arrow function) is to set:

```
var _this = this;
```

and then call

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', _this._mousemove);
```

Without arrow function:

```
export default class DragResizer {
  constructor(handleElement, variableElement) {
    this.handleElement = window.document.getElementsByClassName(handleElement)[0];
    this.variableElement = window.document.getElementsByClassName(variableElement)[0];

    console.log('bind');

    var _this = this;
    this.handleElement.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', _this._mousemove);
      console.log('down');
    });

    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
      console.log('up');
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', _this._mousemove);
    });
  }

  _mousemove(event) {
    console.log('move');
    this.variableElement.style.flexBasis = `${event.clientX}px`;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE** I've rewritten the above using arrow functions. Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/80x3hfbj/) with below code slightly modified to show it working.

```
export default class DragResizer {
  constructor(handleElement, variableElement) {
    this.handleElement = window.document.getElementsByClassName(handleElement)[0];
    this.variableElement = window.document.getElementsByClassName(variableElement)[0];

    console.log('bind');

    var _this = this;
    this.handleElement.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', this._mousemove);
      console.log('down');
    });

    window.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
      console.log('up');
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', this._mousemove);
    });
  }

  _mousemove(event) {
    console.log('move');
    this.variableElement.style.flexBasis = `${event.clientX}px`;
  }
}
```